# using an section of deep object keys as local variables

Tags: javascript

I don't know what this would be called but, suppose I have:

```
var object = {something:{really:{long:{x:2,y:3,z:null}}}};

//is there a way I can go like:

with (object.something.really.long) {
    z = x * y;
}

console.log(object);
//output: {something:{really:{long:{x:2,y:3,z:6}}}}
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: No, I just made up the "with" bit, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works! There even isn't anything needed to change.
However, as stated by [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), you should avoid using `with` as this would cause bug easily due to ambiguity.

> Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues.
>
> Using with is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict mode. The recommended alternative is to assign the object whose properties you want to access to a temporary variable.

Also, the object comparison would be false as object compare by reference. Anyway, the object will looks like what you said finally.

Comment: Actually, the comparison wouldn't work because `===` between objects does reference comparison...

Comment: You are right as object compare by reference. I overlooked the question as he was asking about with.

Comment: That last line was only to demonstrate what the expected result would be, updated to be more clear

Comment: I did actually end up going with: `var o = object.something.really.long;` which I guess is the better option anyway.